# Escape "\\" on a C# SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been having an issue with C# and SQL queries. I want to update a database entry on an active directory database table, like "domain\user.Account". However, every time I run

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + @"domain\user.Account" + " SET AccountStatus_id=3 WHERE Account_id=" + a.AccountId;"
```

It comes up with the error of "invalid syntax near '\'". I've tried escaping it through multiple ways, but it always displays the same error.

What can I do here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put `[]` around it. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection for account ID.

Comment: [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/2029983) It's 2021; you should have stopped injecting your parameters decades ago.

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) so you don't need to escape characters, and other benefits.

Comment: To be clear, the suggestions about parameters will help _only_ with the account ID - **not** the table name.

Comment: I must admit, having a table/view called `domain\user.Account` is a very poor choice of an object name.

Comment: @Larnu I know, but that's the way that the database is constructed, as it has Active Directory attached for permissions and such. This is a company database, not a personal one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers (such as schema names) with reserved characters need to be marked with `[`/`]` in SQL Server, so if this is the `Account` table in the `domain\user` schema, then:

```sql
UPDATE [domain\user].Account SET ...
```

However, if this is the `domain\user.Account` table in the default schema, then:

```sql
UPDATE [domain\user.Account] SET ...
```

In either case, you *should absolutely* use parameters for the values, i.e.

```sql
SET AccountStatus_id=3 WHERE Account_id=@accountId;
```

Tools like Dapper can make that painless for you, for example:

```cs
connection.Execute(@"
    UPDATE /* your choice here! */
    SET AccountStatus_id=3
    WHERE Account_id=@accountId;",
    new { accountId = a.AccountId });
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of parametrization. After so many attempts at this, I was getting paranoid and trying to decompose all this stuff. Nevertheless, your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If table name contains characters except letters, numbers, and underscores then you need to add `[]` in SQL Server.
If it is mysql, mariadb etc, then need to add **``**

In this case table name is `domain\user.Account` which contains `\`. Instead of that use `[domain\user.Account]`